# I want to fetch ADFS server users using Auth0 API in Asp.net C# mvc. Is it possible to do so?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, angular

I have implemented ADFS user's login using Auth0 API in ASP.Net and everything is working fine. Now my requirement is that i want to fetch all the ADFS users using auth0 api. Is it possible that I can fetch all ADFS users via auth0 api?

Answer (score 0):

yes you can find it here [AUth0 Adfs login](https://auth0.com/docs/connections/enterprise/adfs).
here they have given step by step solution